# Checkbox select all/ unselect all on anchor link using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to select all checkbox using anchor link. when click on link, it should select all checkboxes and change text to unselect all.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Select and deselect all checkboxes using jquery</title>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        //select all checkboxes
        $("#select_all").click(function(){  //"select all" change 
            $(".checkbox").prop('checked', 'checked'); //change all ".checkbox" checked status
        });

        //".checkbox" change 
        $('.checkbox').change(function(){ 
            //uncheck "select all", if one of the listed checkbox item is unchecked
            if(false == $(this).prop("checked")){ //if this item is unchecked
                $("#select_all").prop('checked', false); //change "select all" checked status to false
            }
            //check "select all" if all checkbox items are checked
            if ($('.checkbox:checked').length == $('.checkbox').length ){
                $("#select_all").prop('checked', true);
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
 <a id="select_all" href="javascript:void(0);">check all</a>
 <ul>
    <li><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="check[]"> This is Item 1</li>
    <li><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="check[]"> This is Item 2</li>
    <li><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="check[]"> This is Item 3</li>
    <li><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="check[]"> This is Item 4</li>
    <li><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="check[]"> This is Item 5</li>
    <li><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="check[]"> This is Item 6</li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

when click on link, it's not selecting any checkboxes. what mistake am i doing?

Comment: The property checked needs to be set to a Boolean value. Maybe you want to set the attribute checked instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) in the following way to toggle the checkboxes:

```js
$(function() {
  //select all checkboxes
  $("#select_all").click(function() { //"select all" change 
    $(".checkbox").data('checked', !$(".checkbox").data('checked')).prop('checked', $(".checkbox").data('checked')); //change all ".checkbox" checked status
    if ($(".checkbox").data('checked')) {
      this.innerHTML = "uncheck all";
    } else
      this.innerHTML = "check all";
  });

  //".checkbox" change 
  $('.checkbox').change(function() {
    //uncheck "select all", if one of the listed checkbox item is unchecked
    if (false == $(this).prop("checked")) { //if this item is unchecked
      $("#select_all").prop('checked', false); //change "select all" checked status to false
    }
    //check "select all" if all checkbox items are checked
    if ($('.checkbox:checked').length == $('.checkbox').length) {
      $("#select_all").html("uncheck all");
      $(".checkbox").data('checked', true);
    }
    else {
    $("#select_all").html("check all");
      $(".checkbox").data('checked', false);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="select_all" href="javascript:void(0);">check all</a>
<ul>
  <li><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="check[]"> This is Item 1</li>
  <li><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="check[]"> This is Item 2</li>
  <li><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="check[]"> This is Item 3</li>
  <li><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="check[]"> This is Item 4</li>
  <li><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="check[]"> This is Item 5</li>
  <li><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="check[]"> This is Item 6</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks.. when any one of the checkbox is unchecked, how to change text to check all

Comment: @GònghéguóHokkien i've updated the code, you can do so in the `.change` event callback that you've written

Answer (score 0):

you need to set boolean true on click of select all anchor tag. But you want to uncheck select all on uncheck of any of the checkbox which is not possible as you are using anchor tag, you nee to use checkbox for select all also.

code snipped

```js
$(function(){
   $(function(){
        //select all checkboxes
        $("#select_all").click(function(){  //"select all" change 
            $(".checkbox").prop('checked', $(this).is(':checked')); //change all ".checkbox" checked status
        });

        //".checkbox" change 
        $('.checkbox').change(function(){ 
           /* //uncheck "select all", if one of the listed checkbox item is unchecked
            if(false == $(this).prop("checked")){ //if this item is unchecked
                $("#select_all").prop('checked', false); //change "select all" checked status to false
            }
            //check "select all" if all checkbox items are checked
            if ($('.checkbox:checked').length == $('.checkbox').length ){
                $("#select_all").prop('checked', true);
            }*/
            
            //shorthand for above code
            $("#select_all").prop('checked', $('.checkbox:checked').length == $('.checkbox').length);
        });
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    
 <a href="javascript:void(0);"><input type="checkbox" id="select_all">check all</a>
 <ul>
    <li><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="check[]"> This is Item 1</li>
    <li><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="check[]"> This is Item 2</li>
    <li><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="check[]"> This is Item 3</li>
    <li><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="check[]"> This is Item 4</li>
    <li><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="check[]"> This is Item 5</li>
    <li><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="check[]"> This is Item 6</li>
</ul>
```